# Using a UIPickerView with custom values

Tags: cocoa-touch

Im using a navigation controller and a normal view. In the view I'd like a UIPickerView with custom values in it. It would have one column with about 15 values in it. And I want the ability to add an action to each value.

Is there any way I can do this using Xcode? I can't seem to find the corrent help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the documentation for **UIPickerViewDelegate**.

In order to have an action for each value you will implement *pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:* and have a different action based on which row was selected.

For the contents of the rows you can implement *pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:* if your contents are simple text.

If you want custom drawn contents you can provide a custom view for each row with the *pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:* method.

See the UICatalog example that is available in the iPhone Developer examples.